# Cohomology of colimit is limit of cohomology ? (group cohomology)

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology, limits-colimits

In *Homotopy theoretic methods in group cohomology*, Henn's part, section 1.2, the example following definition 1 has the following sentence

"the cohomology $H^*(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ of a group $G$, which is the colimit of a sequence of homomorphisms $G_n\to G_{n+1}$, is the limit $\varprojlim_n H^*(G_n,\mathbb{F}_p)$"

However, that doesn't seem clear to me, even in the nicest cases.

Indeed, let's say that all groups involved are discrete to simplify things, and, still to simplify, assume each morphism $G_n\to G_{n+1}$ is injective. Then it's pretty clear that $BG = \mathrm{colim} BG_n$ (since everything is discrete, we may look at $BG$ as $|NG|$ where $N$ is the nerve, then $|-|$ preserves colimits, and we may check by hand that $N$ preserves this special case of colimit), and that $BG_n\to BG_{n+1}$ is the inclusion of a subcomplex (again, I'm using $BK = |NK|$), hence we have the Milnor exact sequence $$0\to \varprojlim^1 H^{i-1}(G_n,\mathbb{F}_p) \to H^i(G,\mathbb{F}_p) \to \varprojlim H^i(G_n,\mathbb{F}_p)$$ (one can also derive this sequence algebraically from a $G$-projective resolution of $\mathbb{F}_p$, noting that under our hypotheses it is also $G_n$ projective for all $n$, and that $\hom_G(P_\bullet, M) = \varprojlim \hom_{G_n}(P_\bullet, M)$)

So even with all these nice hypotheses the statement I quoted would mean that $\varprojlim^1 H^{i-1}(G_n,\mathbb{F}_p) = 0$, but that's a bit unreasonable to expect, isn't it ? Morally, the induced maps $H^{i-1}(G_n,\mathbb{F}_p)\to H^{i-1}(G_k, \mathbb{F}_p), k\leq n$ could have bigger and bigger images.

> So are there some unstated assumptions behind the quoted claim ? Or is it true in full generality ? If it is, how can one prove it ?

Comment: @RyleeLyman : what do you mean ? Which properties ?

Comment: Perhaps one can show that the system $H^{i-1}(G_n)$ has the Mittag-Leffler property in which case $\varprojlim^1$ vanishes. If the $G_n \to G_{n+1}$ are injective, you may have a chance that the $H^{i-1}(G_{n+1}) \to H^{i-1}(G_n)$ are surjective which implies Mittag-Leffler.

Comment: @PaulFrost : that's what I was referring to in my "morally" part : for arbitrary inclusions, it seems unreasonable to expect the Mittag-Leffler condition to be met, isn't it ? Unless there's something I'm missing, I would be glad to find out that they actually satisfy ML

Comment: If this is true then it's pretty subtle as it's false for cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. For instance $B\mathbb{Q}$ has nontrivial $H^2$, namely $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$, but it's a colimit of circles by the standard mapping telescope. I don't immediately see a counterexample to the finite coefficients case, though. Also just to remark that you can use the Milnor sequence for an arbitrary colimit of groups, as those always give rise to colimits of $BG$s.

Comment: @KevinCarlson thank you for your remark and the example, it's a good sanity check. And I didn't know that about $B$, I'll have to think about it

Comment: Oops, I meant homotopy colimits!

Comment: @KevinCarlson: it did sound weird, thank you for confirming haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from the fact that cohomology (with coefficients in a field) is dual to homology.  Note first that $H_*(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ always is the colimit of the $H_*(G_n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ (homology always preserves homotopy colimits).  But the dual of a colimit is just the limit of the duals (this is immediate from the universal property of the colimit).  So, taking duals of homology, we conclude that $H^*(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is the limit of the $H^*(G_n,\mathbb{F}_p)$.

As mentioned in the comments, it is not true with integer coefficients: $\mathbb{Q}$ is the colimit of $G_n=\frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{Z}$ but $H^2(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ is nontrivial while $H^2(G_n,\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial for all $n$.  The proof above fails for integer coefficients since cohomology is no longer simply the dual of homology (and indeed, the nontriviality of $H^2(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ comes from the Ext term in the universal coefficient theorem).